# Error in ado.net crud operations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I want to update details. I have code in a data access class. But after executing `ExecuteScalar()`, it goes to the catch block and shows an exception as `null`.

Program :

```
public bool UpdateData(Customer objcust) // passing model class object because it contains all customer properties.
{
    SqlConnection con = null;
   // string result = "";
    //int rows = 0;
    try
    {
        string connectionString = @"server=(local)\SQLExpress;database=CustDemo;integrated Security=SSPI;";
        con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Customer SET Name = @Name , Address = @Address, Gender =@Gender , City=@City WHERE Customer.CustomerID = @CustomerID",con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", objcust.Name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", objcust.Gender);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", objcust.Address);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", objcust.City);

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't pass the customer ID parameter. Please check and it's null.

Comment: Can any of the values you assign to your parameters be null ?

Comment: I dont think so it can be null if it is the value does not exist in the table she cannot update!! @GuidoG

Comment: you should read @AT-2016 comment above it is the correct answer to your problem I think

Answer (score 0):

Instead of  `cmd.ExecuteScalar();` Try to use

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery ();
```

`ExecuteNonQuery` is used specifically executing UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE statements.